# Can we render multiple templates in just a part of an LWC component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

With [multiple templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_render) we can replace the entire content of a component with a different html file. Does anybody know if its possible to do this with just a part of the component rather than its entire content?  For example, I want part of the page to be static and part to be conditionally rendered from one of two html files:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|  template1.html / template2.html  |
+-----------------------------------+
| This content will remain constant |
+-----------------------------------+
```

for instance:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={showTemplate1}>
        template1.html
    </template>

    <template if:false={showTemplate1}>
        template2.html
    </template>

    <div>
        this content will remain constant
    </div>
</template>
```

Is there a way I can achieve this without having to put the content into two separate entire components?

Comment: Depending on the size and complexity of your templates this might not be a good approach but have you read the documentation on [slots?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_slots)

Comment: I'd certainly consider simply making template 1 and template 2 actually child components if there's any complexity, then simply conditionally render one or the other.

Comment: @nbrown You really ought to have added an answer.

Comment: @nbrown presumably with slots I'd still be best off using child components?

Comment: It's my understanding from the slot documentation you can pass any valid markup into a slot. If I come up with a good example I may add it as an answer but as of right now I've only read about slots and haven't put them into practice.